# Падежные окончания: всегда ли следует склонять неодушевлённые позывные, клички, прозвища и т. п. по правилам одушевлённых?

Tags: орфография, склонение, окончания, раздельно-дефис, одушевленность

Скажите, если в тексте персонажи называют друг друга по позывным, образованным от неодушевлённых предметов, следует ли эти позывные склонять по правилам одушевлённых, ведь за ними реальные люди (то есть, например, в винительном падеже будет "кого", а не "что")? Думаю, да, но, может, бывают разные варианты в литературе? Кстати, нужен ли дефис в таких позывных (тоже думаю, что да):

*— Рубин(-)Один вызывает Алмаз(а-)Четыре, приём.*

*— На связи Алмаз(-)Четыре, вижу Сапфир(а-)Семь. Приём, Рубин(-)Один.*

Comment: А вы на Грамоте.ру задавали этот вопрос? У меня есть большие сомнения по части правомерности замены формы В.п. формой Р..п. при связи военных и секретных агентов. Там требуется точное название, которое нежелательно искажать. Поэтому лучше так: Рубин-Один вызывает Алмаз-Четыре, приём. Обозначать одушевленность можно для обычных прозвищ, но только не в этой сфере.

Comment: Пока не отвечают. Я уже понял, это в их стиле) А ещё они порой игнорируют по-настоящему сложные вопросы, но при этом могут быстро отвечать на достаточно простые. Проверено: задавал каждый день подряд несколько сложных, расписанных, и в какой-то момент между ними задал и попроще. На сложные так и не ответили, зато простой вычленили и соизволили проконсультировать очень быстро)

Comment: Еще бы, вопросов большое количество, а возможности у них наверняка ограничены.  Мне кажется, что вопросы надо задавать кратко и четко, чтобы они "не увильнули" от ответа. А вы в Грамма. ру  вы не пробовали обращаться.?

Comment: Нет, а насколько они авторитетны? Я, конечно, и сюда пришёл потому, что частенько вылезал этот портал при поиске ответов на вопросы, а "Грамота.ру" может не отвечать неделями, даже если им задавать каждый день одни и те же вопросы. Тем не менее они — проверенный годами авторитет (даже учителя в школе советовали их). Насчёт других ничего не знаю.

Comment: Кажется, это Справочная служба русского языка ИРЯ РАН.  Некоторые участники нашего форума задают там вопросы, и они дают очень подробные ответы

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я бы оформила диалог таким образом:
*— Рубин-один вызывает **Алмаза-четыре**, приём.

— На связи Алмаз-четыре, вижу **Сапфира-семь**. Приём, Рубин-один.*

> **6.** В результате олицетворения или употребления слова в переносном значении названия предметов неодушевленных могут употребляться для обозначения лиц, например: *надо пригласить и этого старого **колпака**, этого **пня** трудно убедить, убрать этого **истукана*** (бессердечный или бестолковый человек; ср.: *поставить истукан*)... ср. в поговорках: *Лапоть знай **лаптя**, сапог – **сапога**; Чин **чина** почитай.*

Дефис нужен, правда, числительные *один, четыре, семь* я бы написала со строчной буквы.

И не надо, не езди: посмотри только на **Лаптя** ― и получишь полное представление. [Анатолий Мельник. Авторитет (2000)]
За **Пня** я спокоен ― у него неплохие заговоренные пасы, да и с маневрированием все в порядке… [Дмитрий Емец. Таня Гроттер и колодец Посейдона (2004)]
Потом грустили, подпершись руками. Дарья предложила позвать **Колпака**. Он опять сейчас без жены. [В. М. Шапко. Графомания как болезнь моего серого вещества // «Волга», 2012]

*«Кто поведет?» — Командира полка ловили на слове. «Миннибаев». — «Позывной?» — **«Стрела-девять»**. — «Давайте Миннибаева!..»* (Артем Анфиногенов. А внизу была земля).

[Формы винительного падежа одушевленных и неодушевленных существительных](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/57.htm)